# Unable to connect to webserver on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2

I'm unable to connect to my EC2 instance where I have an apache web server running (also running an Express.js server on a different port). I have updated the security group to allow incoming requests to http and https ports but I continue to get this response in the browser:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
*********** sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I am able to ssh into my EC2 instance.

Other than ensuring that the correct ports are open and that a service is listening on those ports, is there any configuration needed to setup simple web server on EC2?

- Current security group settings:

[image: security group settings]

- Currently open ports (sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN):

[image: open ports]

There are some similar questions posted but they are either vague or have been left for dead

Comment: What do you get, if you try to access using curl/wget with both http and https protocols on the same ec2 instance? And then at client-site on web-browser or on command line with curl/wget, what http status code you see? because this seems to be Apache SSL configuration issue rather than network reach-ability problem.

Comment: @amitd, wget gives me: `$ wget https://ec2-18-218-143-199.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
--2021-04-02 06:45:42--  https://ec2-18-218-143-199.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/
Resolving ec2-18-218-143-199.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com (ec2-18-218-143-199.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com)... 18.218.143.199
Connecting to ec2-18-218-143-199.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com (ec2-18-218-143-199.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com)|18.218.143.199|:443... failed: Connection refused.`

Comment: I don't see any listeners on port `443`. Did you install an SSL certificate on the server, and configure the server to listen on port `443`? Or did you just open port `443` in the security group and assume it would work?

Comment: @ammatthew2 - it looks to me SSL configuration issue. as you can access it using HTTP on browser with allowing security exception, http://ec2-18-218-143-199.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/

Comment: @MarkB, I opened the port but I did not install an SSL certificate. As far as configuring the server to listen to the port, Apache by default should be doing this. And the Express.js server I setup is for sure listening to port 9000

Comment: @iammatthew2 apache by default only listens on port 80. It can't listen on port `443` until you install an SSL certificate. I'm not sure how the Express.js server on port `9000` is even relevant to this issue, if you aren't entering port `9000` in the URL. You are only testing against port `443` currently.

Comment: @MarkB, thanks for the info about the SSL cert. And yes, I was testing the `9000` post by appending it to the url. Based on @amitd's comment I tried accessing that same url using HTTP and it works too.

Comment: This is indeed an SSL/TLS cert issue. Happy to accept an answer if someone wants to post one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install mod_ssl to tell apache to serve httpS connections.
You can use the default (or self signed certificate) to check the connectivity on port 443. If you need a valid ssl certificate, you can get one for free from Let's Encrypt: https://letsencrypt.org/
You can use CertBOT to auto renew certificates: https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/